# Finding the range between two numbers (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to find a way to code something like this:
"Money earned: 200$ - 500$"
I have the first multiplication done (float * 0.002) and now i want to add (float * 0.005) to be able to show the lowest amount of money earned AND the highest amount of money earned. 
Here's what i have so far:

```
float numViews = [viewsHere.text floatValue] * 0.002;
result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", numViews];
```

I would like to add a 0.005 multiplication and print out both results at the same time to be able to have an estimate...

I know this question is hard to understand but i can't seem to find help anywhere.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want (float * 0.002) + (float * 0.005) or Do you want to display like result of (float * 0.002) - result of (float * 0.005) ?

Comment: Result of (float * 0.002) - Result of (float * 0.005)

Answer (score 0):

```
float numViews = [viewsHere.text floatValue] * 0.002;
float numViews2 = [viewsHere.text floatValue] * 0.005;
result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Money earned: $%.2f - $%.2f", numViews, numViews2];
```

Comment: I think you need to fix some code here. The 1st two lines are the same.

Comment: @rmaddy Amended to OP spec, sorry.